# After changing a UseState Hook React component is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I read many topics around these problem but none of them helped to find an answer.

I am using a useEffect to fetch an array of objects "nftRewards". And it's working fine cause I can see them on the console. But the part of the render that depends on this hook is not re-render once it was updated. And I don't understand why.

```
  const [campaignRewardsJson, setCampaignRewardsJson] = useState<nftReward[]>([]);

  const { data: rewards } = useContractRead({
    address: campaignsId,
    abi: campaignABI,
    functionName: 'getRewards',
  });

  async function getRewardObject() {
    var array: nftReward[] = [];
    rewards.map(async (reward, index) => {
      const json = fetch(reward[2]);
      const data = await json.then((res) => res.json());

      const nft: nftReward = {
        title: data.name,
        description: data.description,
        imageURL: data.image,
        price: reward[0],
        quantity: reward[1],
      };

      array.push(nft);
    });
    return array;
  }

  type nftReward = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imageURL: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (rewards) {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        var data = await getRewardObject();

        setCampaignRewardsJson(data);
      };
      // call the function
      fetchData().catch(console.error);
    }
  }, [rewards]);
```

And At the end of my render , I have this but It's never render by react:

```
{campaignRewardsJson.map((reward, index) => (
            <Card direction={{ base: 'column', sm: 'row' }} overflow="hidden" variant="outline">
              <Image objectFit="cover" maxW={{ base: '100%', sm: '200px' }} src={reward.imageURL} alt="Caffe Latte" />

              <Stack>
                <CardBody>
                  <Heading size="md">{reward.title}</Heading>
                  <Text py="2">{reward.description}</Text>
                </CardBody>

                <CardFooter>
                  <Button variant="solid" colorScheme="blue">
                    Mint NFT
                  </Button>
                </CardFooter>
              </Stack>
            </Card>
          ))}
```

Comment: could it be because you don't have a key?  `<Card key={index} direction={{ base: 'column', sm: 'row' }} overflow="hidden" variant="outline">`

Comment: is `rewards` a prop that passed to the component

Comment: Bryan Dellinge, I added a Key and doesn't help. 
Yilmaz, I added the reward hook code , so you can see where it's coming from.

Comment: Your `getRewardObject` function returns an empty array because you do not `await` the `map`'d promises, and the array reference is now shared between the running promises and your react state; the fulfilling promises will fill the array instance with their results but this will not trigger a re-render, because the array instance stays the same. You may want to look into [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thank you Martin, I think that Your comment helps me to understand the issue. But I am not sure where exactly I should use Promise.all cause from what I understand Promise.all is actually a promise that takes an array of promises as an input (an iterable). Then it gets resolved when all the promises get resolved. But In my code, I don't really have concurrent operations.

Comment: @Jeks your `rewards.map` returns promises, thus you have to wait for them all to finish. see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function getRewardObject() {
  var array: nftReward[] = [];

  await Promise.allSettled(
    rewards.map(async (reward, index) => {
      const json = fetch(reward[2]);
      const data = await json.then((res) => res.json());

      const nft: nftReward = {
        title: data.name,
        description: data.description,
        imageURL: data.image,
        price: reward[0],
        quantity: reward[1],
      };

      array.push(nft);
    }));

  return array;
}
```

Comment: I tried, It's not working. I edited my code to add more informations about what rewards is and how it works. I am displaying "campaignRewardsJson" in the console and I see the good result. It's working. My only issue is that it's not rendering once the hook campaignRewardsJson was updated.

Comment: @Jeks updated my answer. should be working now. `Promise.allSettled` will wait for all promises even if either will reject.

Answer (score 0):

If `rewards` is state in this component and type of that is object or array.
When you pass array or object to dependency, every render snapshot will compare with previous version. You may try keyword `useEffect dependency array and object comparison`. for more information.